# instantiate спавнит 2 клона

Tags: c#, unity3d

пытаюсь создать механизм переключения оружия в игре но почему-то когда я нажимаю E в руке появляются вместо одной пушки 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class wearonSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject Gun 
  public GameObject Ruka;
  public GameObject ruka1;
   
  private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
  {
      if (other.CompareTag("gun") || (other.CompareTag("agun")))
      {
          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
          {
              if (Gun.activeInHierarchy == true)
              {
                  
                  Destroy(Gun);
                  other.gameObject.tag = "agun";
                  Instantiate(other.gameObject, Ruka.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, ruka1.transform);
                  Destroy(other.gameObject);
              }  
              Gun = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("agun");
              Gun.GetComponent<gun>().enabled = true;

          }
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: у вас точно срабатывает это условие? `if (Gun.activeInHierarchy == true)`